# Finding out which version of a program is installed from the registry

Tags: c#, registry

I am iterating over the SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall in the registry, what I noticed is that there are some programs that are listed in brackets like: {E05E8183-866A-11D3-97DF-0000F8D8F2E9}, and it has all the information like version and displayName.

Other programs that are not in brackets like 4591AF53-0A6B-4BB9-A335-AFF02C8D5BCD does not have all the information.

Could someone explain why is there a difference and if there is any other way know the version of a software installed.

Comment: Reference that GUID in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\ key, that should give you more insight.

Comment: Ultimately I would have thought the answer to this question entirely depends upon what the actual application is?

Answer (score 1):

You could find out which version of a program installed using Windows MSI installer is installed by going to: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Installer/Products and iterate that.  The GUIDS that you see under that directory is generated by the MSI installer to identify products installed, so it can find them again for uninstall.

Comment: This is only for programs that were installed with windows installer